# Lambda Expressions functional programming

Tags: java, regex, lambda, functional-programming

I have to programm regular expression with lambda expressions for the university. I got stuck by 2 methods in a method.

here is my code:

```
static String ausdruck = "abcd";

public static Function<String, String> Char = (c) -> {
    return (ausdruck.startsWith(c)) ? ausdruck = ausdruck.substring(1,
            ausdruck.length()) : "Value Error";
};

public static BiFunction<Function<String, String>, 
                         Function<String, String>, 
                         Function<String, String>> 
                And = (f1, f2) -> {return null;};
```

what I want to do in the `And` method is: `Char(Char.apply("a"))` -> I want to call the function `f2` with the `f1` as a parameter. 
the Call of the And Method have to look like:

```
And.apply(Char.apply("a"), Char.apply("b"));
```

Comment: I don't think modifying a static variable in a lambda is a good idea... I don't even know whether this is allowed. Also, `Char.apply("a")` does not return another function.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want

```
    Func<Str,Str> f = and( comsume("a"), consume("b") );
    f.apply("abcd"); // "cd"


Func<Str,Str> consume(String x)
    return input->{ 
        if(input.startsWith(x)) return input.substring(x.length());
        else throws new IllegalArgument()
    };


Func<Str,Str> and(Fun<Str,Str> f1, Func<Str,Str> f2)
    return input-> f2.apply(f1.apply(input))
```

`and` is not necessary though, see `Function.andThen` method

```
    f = consume("a").andThen( consume("b) )
```

Unfortunately, there is no "curry"; otherwise, we could do this

```
    f = consume2.curry("a") .andThen (  consume2.curry("b") );

static BiFunc<Str,Str,Str> consume2 = (input,x)-> {...return input.substring(x.length()); ..
```

It's better off if you design your own functional interfaces, with needed methods like curry.

```
interface F1
    String apply(String);
    F1 and(F1);

interface F2
    String apply(String,String);
    F1 curry(String);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to create a function that compones a new function, executing one function with the result of another function. The best way to do this in a lambda would be to return a new lambda.

Try something like this:

```
BiFunction<Function<String, String>, Function<String, String>, Function<String, String>> compose =
            (f1, f2) -> (a -> f2.apply(f1.apply(a)));
```

Example:

```
Function<String, String> upper = s -> s.toUpperCase();
Function<String, String> twice = s -> s + s;
Function<String, String> upperTwice = compose.apply(upper, twice);
System.out.println(upperTwice.apply("foo"));
```

Output is `FOOFOO`.

---

Concerning your concrete example

> the Call of the And Method have to look like:
>   `And.apply(Char.apply("a"), Char.apply("b");`

I do not know exactly what you are trying to do, but I don't think this will work, given your current implementation of `Char`. It seems like you want to compose a lambda to remove `a` with another to remove `b`, but instead `Char.apply("a")` will not create another function, but actually remove `"a"` from your `ausdruck` String! Instead, your `Char` lambda should probably also return another lambda, and that lambda should not modify some `static` variable, but take and return another String parameter.

```
Function<String, Function<String, String>> stripChar = 
            c -> (s -> s.startsWith(c) ? s.substring(1) : "ERROR");
Function<String, String> stripAandC = compose.apply(stripChar.apply("c"), stripChar.apply("a"));
System.out.println(stripAandC.apply("cash"));
```

Output is `sh`.

---

Finally, in case you want to use this with anything other than just `String`, it might make sense to make `compose` an actual method instead of a lambda, so you can make use of generics. Also, you can make this a bit simpler by using `andThen`:

```
public static <A, B, C> Function<A, C> compose(Function<A, B> f1, Function<B,C> f2){
    return f1.andThen(f2);
}
```